# How do I allow a user to input vectors rather than strings?

Tags: python, string, input

I'm trying to make my program allow the user to input vectors of the form (x,y,z) using python's built in input() function.

If entered normally in python with out using the input() function it indexes each vector separately. For example,

```
>>> z = (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)
>>> z[1]
(4, 5, 6)
```

But when I try to use the input function I run into the following problem.

```
>>> z = input('What are the vectors?  ')
What are the vectors?  (1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)
>>> z[1]
'1'
```

Why does using the input function turn it into a string and is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: The user *types* characters, which make up strings. It is up to the programmer to interpret those strings.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, `input` always returns a string. You need to convert the string. For this type of input I recommend using `liter_eval` from the module `ast`:

```
import ast
vectors = ast.literal_eval('(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)')
vectors[1]     #(4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: I was unaware that this was the case for python 3. The ast .literal_eval() function solves my problem completely though. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Kyle If you have experience with Python 2, Python 3's `input()` is basically the same as Python 2's `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `z` is just a string as input by the user.

This string is: `"(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)"` so the second element, `z[1]` is just giving you `"1"`.

If you want an actual vector object you would have to write code to parse the string input by the user. For example, you could delimit based on parentheses and convert the numbers individually.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

you can use eval with input function to the get the same as first.

```
eval(input('Please enter the vector')
```

Comment: Recommending an unguarded `eval` is dangerous. Early in their programming careers, programmers need to be aware of the dangers of constructs like `eval`. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Thanks, I am also new to Python. So was not aware of this thing.